# Is there a way to create a heat map with multiple colour scales in R?

Tags: javascript, r, charts, visualization, echarts4r

I am using the echarts4R library in R to create an interactive heat map (see image attached). The data is structured as below:

| league_name | attribute | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bundesliga | pace | 70 |
| Bundesliga | shooting | 60 |
| Bundesliga | passing | 64 |
| Bundesliga | dribbling | 70 |
| Bundesliga | defending | 62 |
| Bundesliga | physic | 71 |
| La Liga | pace | 70 |
| La Liga | shooting | 62 |
| La Liga | passing | 66 |
| La Liga | dribbling | 70 |

Here is the code I used, where player_att_plot is the data frame with the structure above:

```
player_att_plot %>% 
e_charts(league_name) %>%
 e_heatmap(attribute,value, itemStyle = list(emphasis = list(shadowBlur = 10))) %>% 
e_visual_map(value,inRange = list(color=c("white","green")))
```

Basically I want the heat map to have a color scale specific to each attribute, as opposed to the whole heat map.[Heatmap with echarts4R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcQeb.png)

I tried splitting the data frame and plot into separate series and then plotting, but was unsuccessful. There might be another package that might be more suited for the example, any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach here would be to use the alpha aesthetic:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(league_name, attribute, fill = attribute, alpha = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "gray") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  ggsci::scale_fill_startrek() +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

Obviously you can use whichever fill palette you prefer.

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(league_name = rep(c("Bundesliga", "La Liga", "Ligue 1",
                                     "Premier League", "Serie A"), each = 6),
                 attribute = factor(rep(c("pace", "shooting", "passing", 
                                        "dribbling", "defending", "physic"), 5),
                                    c("pace", "shooting", "passing", 
                                      "dribbling", "defending", "physic")),
                 value = sample(59:72, 30, TRUE))
```

Comment: How to use the same color in all them? but the gradent is feautre based

Comment: @PeCaDe can you explain a bit more about what you mean? In your question you say you want a color scale specific to each attribute. In my example, each attribute has its own color scale from white to an attribute-specific color. Please explain in more detail.